# In order to be a gas does the pressure exerted by the gas has to be more than the atmospheric pressure?

Tags: homework, everyday-chemistry, gas-laws

In order to be a gas does the pressure exerted by the gas has to be more than the atmospheric pressure?
Really simple, I think yes to this question but teacher says no. So what is your view into this?

Comment: Is the question inspired by boiling of gas

Comment: @DSinghvi I don't think you can boil a gas, and no.

Comment: @AwesomeFlame123 It's a joke - if you want to boil sth it's vapor pressure should be at least as big as the pressure of the atmosphere - it doesn't say anything about gas pressure generally.

Comment: It would be nice if you could give your questions more meaningful titles. It would be even nicer if you could include your reasoning, why you think your answer is correct and the other one is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your teacher is right. For example, at room temperature, the pressure of water vapor over a pond or lake might be around 25 torr; that's less than atmospheric pressure, but the water vapor is undeniably a gas.

Maybe your confusion stems from a belief that gases must be produced by boiling liquids (since a liquid must have a vapor pressure equal to the external pressure before it begins to boil). But a liquid can also become a gas through evaporation, no matter what the external pressure is.

In **evaporation**, molecules escape from the liquid's surface and become a gas.
Molecules in the liquid are in constant motion, and they frequently collide with each other. Every now and then one will get knocked off the surface of the liquid by the others. This can happen at any temperature or pressure the liquid exists at.

In **boiling**, bubbles of gas form throughout the liquid. This can only happen when the temperature is high enough to make the vapor pressure equal to the external pressure.

Comment: But doesn't a gas have to exceed atmospheric pressure to become a gas? Then how can it be a gas.

Comment: Certainly a liquid boils when its vapor pressure reaches atmospheric pressure... but a liquid can become a gas at temperatures and pressures lower than its boiling point by evaporation.

Comment: That is what that has always confused me, how can something be a gas at lower temperatures and pressures but it boils when its vapor pressure reaches atmospheric pressure. How can this be? You said evaporation but can you be more specific.

Comment: I've edited the difference between boiling and evaporation into the answer.

Comment: How can they escape liquid's surface? Just like that?

Comment: Molecules in the liquid are in constant motion, and they frequently collide with each other. Every now and then one will get knocked off the surface of the liquid by the others.

Comment: Oh, Only If I knew this earlier then I wouldn't be so confused. So just to be clear, a substance has to exert more pressure above the atmospheric pressure? For it to be a gas, not taking evaporation into account.

Comment: Think about what the molecules are doing to keep it clear. In a liquid, they're churning around but sticking together; in a gas, they're moving like rifle bullets, and not sticking together much at all. The higher the temperature, the faster the molecules move. In boiling, the liquid molecules are moving so fast that they break away from each other, even when they're buried inside the liquid. The bubbles have to form with enough pressure to push back the atmosphere on top of the liquid, or they'll be squashed. In evaporation, molecules are being knocked off the liquid surface by collisions.

Comment: Ok then, I got your point, now lets look at evaporation, once something is evaporated and is a gas can it exist as a gas forever even if the pressure and temperature is much higher?

Answer (score 1):

No. Suppose we had a container containing nothing but water.  Suppose it is only half full, so there is empty space. **There is no  pressure from other gases.** If we heat this container enough, the water will boil and eventually turn completely into a gas. 
In short, clearly other things influence the state of matter in everyday life besides pressure from atmospheric gases. In this example, I illustrate how water evaporating in a vacuum is determined by temperature.  I think  this is a good example because it involves just one substance and doesn't bring into question how to think about mixed gases and partial pressures.

There is an extremely useful equation that connects these relationships beautifully:

$PV = nRT$

P stands for pressure, V for volume, T for temperature, n for the number of molecules, and R is a constant.

This equation basically says that
*any change in pressure or volume to a closed system of gas will result in a corresponding change to the temperature of the system.*

Thus, as long as $P_1V_1\neq P_2V_2$, you can always think about a change in volume or pressure as a change in temperature for a closed system.

Comment: Your italicized sentence is incorrect; 1) a closed system has a constant number of molecules and 2) you can easily change volume and pressure without changing moles of gas or temperature, e. g., half the pressure and double the volume. Also, the ideal gas equation has nothing to do with why substances change state; an ideal gas *never* changes state.

Comment: @FredSenese Thank you for your corrections. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know Dalton's law of partial pressure that "in a mixture of non-reacting gases, the total pressure exerted is equal to the sum of the partial pressures of the individual gases"
And since pressure is non-negative quantity then:

P(total)=P1 + P2 + ... + Pn

SO the pressure of gas in atmosphere in fact, cannot be greater than atmospheric pressures .

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Dalton%27s_law_of_partial_pressures.png

And also I am not saying that gas stored in container cannot have pressure greater than atmosphere . The best example is your LPG cylinder.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that a gas cannot exceed atmospheric pressure, then how is something going to be a gas if it cannot exceed atmospheric pressure?

Comment: Is it the substances intermolecular forces that determine if it can be a gas or not at a specific temperature.

Comment: @AwesomeFlame123 Who said gas cannot exist above atmospheric pressure. I just said that the gases in ATMOSPHERE which surrounds us, we breathe in cannot exceed atmospheric pressure by definition